# Trouble switching from DHCP to a static IP on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, ip

When I installed Kali Linux 64bit, I forgot to set up a static IP address, and now DHCP determines my address with my router. I have already modified `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/network/interfaces` to declare my address as static. However my local address is assigned with DHCP as "192.168.0.15". I have modified the files listed above to grab a static address "192.168.0.22" instead of the DHCP one. Everything is fine when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`, however I need a script to run at startup to do this for me so that my address after execution of the script is "192.168.0.22"

How can I go about doing this?

Also, in my router login page after I restart the wlan0 interface I see this

```
unknown: 192.168.0.22: 00:0D:A5:AE:48:D3: Self-assigned: Wireless
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.22 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Try replacing `auto wlan0` with `allow-hotplug`? See if that changes your issue?

Comment: You should first learn how the DHCP client is triggered. There's a high chance that you are accidentally running some piece of software at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kali with the default Gnome 3 desktop environment, NetworkManager will attempt to configure the network for you, and will default to DHCP.

You can fix this one of two ways. First, you can configure the network through the graphical utility in the system settings.

Second, you can tell NetworkManager to ignore the interface, allowing you to configure it manually through the standard Debian configuration files. This can be done by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and ensuring the file has the following content:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Finally, restart the service with `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly just set the ip assigned to Kali as static in your router.
Say your IPv4 was 192.168.0.2 then you could just assign it as static in your router and provided you're using an installed version of Kali not a live cd then it should always end up with the same address.

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem. When i edit /etc/network/interfaces file, i forgot to add "allow-hotplug eth0 ". That works for me. And following is my /etc/network/interfaces file.
`/etc/network/interfaces`

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.22

netmask 255.255.255.0

gateway 192.168.0.1